# How to translate "sapient" (as a level of sentience)?

Tags: single-word-requests, biology

"sapient" has at least 3 distinct meanings in English:

1. *wise*, *sage*
2. being member of the species *homo sapiens*, i.e., being *human*
3. being member of a species (or other category),
   whose members are generally *sufficiently sentient to be self-aware*.
   (Like humans are, but not necessarily limited to only humans.)

How would one capture that third meaning in Esperanto?

I'm looking for an adjective or noun, so that the word or expression could be used in *"Mi estas <?>."*

Comment: (Using this for [translating the "Creator's Code"](https://github.com/Xe/creators-code/pull/8), even though the English original [was changed from "sapient" to "sentient"](https://github.com/Xe/creators-code/commit/cec3e775462cc2981fc2d92b4f49bbd698d0168b).)

Answer (score 1):

*self awareness* can be translated as *memkonscio*.

You could say something like:

```
Delfenoj estas memkonsciaj bestoj.
```

Comment: So being in a category of entities potentially capable of that would be _memkonscikapablarana_ / _memkonscikapablarano_. Is there a less unwieldy way to express that?

Comment: Work on what Eduardo suggested, _kategorio/klaso/grupo de memkonsciaj bestoj_ and later _ano de tiu kategorio estas ekz. delfeno_.

Answer (score 1):

Though *memkonscia, altkonscia* is fine and corresponds to sapient/self aware,
I would translate the latin *sapiens* either as neologism (latin!) *sapiensa* (how else to translate "homo sapiens" sensibly), or better
as [***kogna***](https://glosbe.com/en/eo/cognition) [Glosbe], cognitive refering to **cognition** (*kogno*), mental self-reflection.

Same as *mamuloj* (mammals) one could have the category *kognuloj* (sapient species).

See also [***kogni***](https://vortaro.net/#kogni_k) [PIV].

Because of the typical overspecification of terms in Esperanto dictionary definitions, here the English (maybe too general) definition of Glosbe:

> ***Cognition*** The operation of the mind by which an organism becomes aware of objects of thought or perception; it includes the mental activities associated with thinking, learning, and memory.

Comment: Can _kogna_ really be used in the sense of _able of cognition_ rather than just that of _related to cognition_? The occurrences at https://glosbe.com/eo/en/kogna seem to mostly capture the latter.

Comment: Yes, one has to speak of _candidates_.